# Function Of Any Line?

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

If I were to scribble a line of varying curves into a sheet of paper and for each value of X there was only a single value of Y, how can I go about finding the function for such a line in a way that is preferably practical and not overly time consuming.

Comment: Too broad. Begin with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution may be to digitize the curve and then fit the data using regression.  Sometimes I want to use graphical textbook data in a program.  First, I take a picture of the graph in the book.  Second, I upload the picture to a website that allows me to digitize the curve.  My favorite such website is http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/app/.  Third, I download the (x,y) coordinates from the website as a CSV text file.  Fourth, I read the CSV data into a spreadsheet, or into another program.  Fifth, I will sometimes try to fit the data to some function that is available in the spreadsheet program.  The choice of function depends on the shape of the curve.  Sometimes I have to use a special curve fitting program, instead of the spreadsheet.  Sixth, I take the function parameters from the curve fitting program, and put them into my program.

Comment: Thank you so much! What I was really getting at was, what software could assist me in this process, and you lead me in the right direction.