# Polar coordinate for complicated curves

Tags: problem-solving, approximation, polar-coordinates, approximation-theory

In general polar representation of a closed curve is done by coordinate $(\theta,r(\theta))$, $\theta\in (0,360)$.

When working with real data, I got a closed curves whose graph looks like the below
[image]

I want to approximate this type of closed curve by some polar equation. But I doubt if it possible or not.

Note that, here we will get points like $(\theta,r^1(\theta)),(\theta,r^2(\theta)),(\theta,r^3(\theta)),\ldots$, that is for same $\theta$ we may get different $r(\theta)$.

Could anyone please suggest how to approximate this type curves using polar coordinate system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a link to a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023474) that may be useful.  The link will indicate a way to represent the curve as a series of data points, which could be the first step in developing the equations.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the polar coordinate system"? Do you only want curves of the form $(r(\theta), \theta)$? Or are parameterized curves ok, e.g. $(r(t), \theta(t))$? As you say, for the former it won't be possible to represent curves that "double back" on themselves.

Comment: @Louis Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to me that the answer to the question in the link relates to fitting the data points with curves in Cartesian plan. But in my case I want to see if I can fit polar equation to the data point.

Comment: @user7530 Yes, I want curves of the form (r(θ),θ). Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @janak  If you have the data points in cartesian coordinates, it should be easy to convert them to polar coordinates.  It is an extra step, but if your curve fitting procedure requires polar coordinates, the conversion step may have to be part of your solution.

Comment: @Louis I have polar coordinates but for a given $\theta$ I have different values of $r(\theta)$ ( as user7530 describe this fact as by "double back"). Then how can I define the polar equation passing through all these points??

Comment: @user7530 Could please explain what is "double back" curve. Initially I thought it is a curve for which $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x\neq y$. But after some google search I got confused about the definition of that curve.